# Вывести все уникальные пары значений MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет.

есть таблица с парами значений:

№  | Column1  |  Column2

---

1 | Value 1  |  Value 2

---

2 | Value 2  |  Value 1

---

3 | Value 3  |  Value 1

---

4 | Value 4  |  Value 2

Мне нужно вывести уникальные значения для всех вариантов пар из этой таблицы
т.е. пара (Value 1 и Value 2) формально одно и тоже что и (value 2 и Value 1), соответственно мне нужно вывести в результате только 3 строки. Как это возможно реалзиовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM table
WHERE Column1 > Column2
UNION 
SELECT Column2, Column1
FROM table
WHERE Column2 >= Column1
```

?

Comment: а `where` тут для скорости (юниона), или зачем?

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Действительно самый легкий способ

Comment: teran у меня без where запрос выдал не тот результат, который хотелось.

Comment: да, че то я туплю :)

Comment: @teran Чтобы из пары дубликатов оставить только один. Увы, у SQL Server нет функций LEAST() и GREATEST(). А строить их аналоги на CASE - не уверен, что будет быстрее. И всё равно от сортировки не убежать.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test
(
  col1 VARCHAR(255),
  col2 VARCHAR(255)
)
;

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('val1', 'val2'), ('val2', 'val1'), ('val3', 'val1'), ('val4', 'val1');

select t.*
from test t
where (col1, col2) not in (select col2, col1 from test)
UNION
select t.*
from test t
where (col1, col2) in (select col2, col1 from test)
and col1 > col2
;
```